# How is the initial kube config file created in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Note: To generate a Kubeconfig file for other users, you need to have admin permissions in the cluster to create service accounts and roles. And these admin permissions is given to the default/admin/initial kube-config file that created while setting up the cluster.

When a cluster created on minikube or k3s or k3d. We get a kube config file directly & by using this Kube config file we can create many other (by making request to the api-server, to create service account token) kube-configs for different users.

But how is this default/admin/initial kube config file is created without requiring access to the api-server?

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of research, I found the following information

Different authentication mechanism exists for authenticating requests coming to the api-server
Regardless of Initial or nth kube-config, the creation process of kube-config is same.
See the below process

The Kube-Config creation process is simple

- Pre-requisites

  - Need to have certificates of the cluster CA
  - If certificates is used for auth, Need to have a public-private cert of the user for whom the kube-config is being created
  - If token is used for auth, Need to have a service account token of the user for whom the kube-config is being created
  - IP address of the API server (usually a load balancer IP)
- Process

```
KUBERNETES_PUBLIC_ADDRESS=43.8.5.8

kubectl config set-cluster kubernetes-the-hard-way \
  --certificate-authority=ca.pem \
  --embed-certs=true \
  --server=https://${KUBERNETES_PUBLIC_ADDRESS}:443

kubectl config set-credentials admin \
  --client-certificate=admin.pem \
  --client-key=admin-key.pem

kubectl config set-context kubernetes-the-hard-way \
  --cluster=kubernetes-the-hard-way \
  --user=admin

kubectl config use-context kubernetes-the-hard-way
```

After provisioning cluster myself, I have understood the following

The initial/admin kube-config uses certificate mechanism for authentication that's why it doesn't not require API calls to the api-server

Check this page to see [how certs are generated for these components](https://github.com/prabhatsharma/kubernetes-the-hard-way-aws/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md)

After the server is up & running we [create the admin config as mentioned here](https://github.com/prabhatsharma/kubernetes-the-hard-way-aws/blob/master/docs/10-configuring-kubectl.md) using the certificates created in the above process.

After this any kube-config created can use either the certificate method or service account method

I highly recommend provisioning a Kubernetes cluster yourself to get more understanding & this guide can help you with that [AWS](https://github.com/prabhatsharma/kubernetes-the-hard-way-aws) [GCP](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)